# yaml files to create models are the same in Doctrine 2.0?

Tags: doctrine

i wonder if the yaml files for creating models in Doctrine 2 are the same as those in Doctrine 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not the same. You can check the new syntax in the [doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/yaml-mapping).

Note that annotation seems to be the prefered way to map entities in Doctrine 2 (see [annotation reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/annotations-reference) and [basic mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/basic-mapping)).

Edit: seems like there is a tool converting Doctrine 1.x schema to Doctrine 2 schema. I can't test here right now but you can try it. [See documentation here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/introduction#installing:pear).

```
doctrine orm:convert-d1-schema
```

Comment: but im using mysql workbench with doctrine plugin. it creates yaml files only. then i have to create the models from the yaml files. that seems to be the only way. i dont quite enjoy to create 20-50 tables without GUI like workbench. is there a way to get this to work with Doctrine 2.0? and what is the class and function for creating models from yaml files? I cant find it in the documentation. in 1.2 it was (i think) Doctrine_Core::create_models_from_yaml()

Comment: I edited my answer. Also note that Doctrine 2 is still in early alpha stage and as such still lack useful tools.

Comment: ok i guess its better for me to stick with Doctrine 1.2 after all and switch back to 2.0 in a year or so=)